# How to Configure Sidekiq in Docker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, docker-compose

I need to configure Sidekiq in Docker.Below the docker compose file configuration i am using for build.I am getting **cannot locate specified docker file** error while building sidekiq. Without sidekiq configuration docker compose build getting success. How to configure sidekiq server in Docker?

```
version: '3'
volumes:  
postgres_data: {} 

services:
redis:
image: redis
command: redis-server
ports:
 - "6379:6379"
app:    
build:      
 context: .      
 dockerfile: /Users/admin/git/generic/myapp/docker/app/Dockerfile 
 depends_on:      
 - db  
 ports:      
 - 3000:3000
db:    
image: postgres 
volumes:      
- postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
web:    
build:      
context: .      
dockerfile: /Users/admin/git/generic/myapp/docker/web/Dockerfile  
depends_on:      
  - app    
 ports:      
  - 80:80
 sidekiq:
   build: .
   command: bundle exec sidekiq
    depends_on:
     - redis
```

Comment: Please be careful to preserve the indentation when including a yaml file in a question. The indetation could be related to the issue you are having. Can you update the post again, with the correct indentation from your source file?

Comment: Ok.Is this issue related to indentation?

Comment: It could be - docker-compose is sensitive to this.

Comment: If indentation is a problem then it should throw error initially itself.it won't run and will show error.Is this correct?It is building app,web,redis,postgres and finally only throwing this error

Comment: Since you're locating the context and `Dockerfile` in your `web` and `app`, you need to do the same for sidekiq. From what I'm seeing, your `docker-compose.yml` isn't in the same directory of your project and `sidekiq` is not understanding what it should be. Either add the `context` and `dockerfile` to sidekiq, or move your `docker-compose.yml` to the project's folder.

Comment: Ok thanks.I will make change.